# How to find whether the given URL will redirect or not using any script?

Tags: c#, php, javascript, html, http

I have a text document with over 2,50,000 website URLs listed. Going through each URL, if it redirects me to a particular URL (different site), I would like to save it to another text file.

I'm C# developer and I know how to read or write to files and small bits and pieces but looking for best logic or way to do the above task and script in any programming language possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you working on? This sounds pretty weird.

Comment: curiosity = step towards invention anyway its some kind of marketing tactical project am working on, can't provide any more detail sorry as its bit confidential, oh by the way you got nice blog ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    var location = resp.Headers["Location"];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("url is redirected to " + location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a bash script. something like

```
#!/bin/bash

$SITESFILE=/path/to/your/input/file
$OUTPUTFILE=/path/to/your/output/file
$TARGETURL=http://where.to/redirect

for SITE in `cat $SITESFILE`; do
  REDIRHEADER=`curl -i $SITE | head -n15 | grep -i 'Location: $TARGETURL'`
  test -n "$REDIRHEADER" && echo $SITE >> $OUTPUTFILE
done;
```

You will need cURL installed.